# Detecting Virtual MAC Address?

Tags: javascript, c#, virtual

I have a list of MAC Address.
How can I detect which ones are Virtual MAC Addresses that have been generated from VPN,VM, Virtual Box, or others software...

please help me!

Comment: you really can't. there is/was a segment of manufacturer, but nothing to prevent that from being fake.

Answer (score 2):

You may find [this list of virtual machine MAC addresses](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/data-center/mac-address-scorecard-for-common-virtual-machine-platforms/) handy, but as dandavis says in his comment, there is no way to know for sure.

Comment: i would think that on a managed network with nothing crazy going on, that list would be pretty solid if the hosts still play ball (written  in 2008)

Comment: @hcs: Thanks you  so much! But Im afraid your list is not enough to check. I need a full list of Vendor...I found this result in GG search . But they are not enough.

Comment: maybe you can spot a pattern if you gather a list of all the ones you're using.

Comment: @dandavis: I know every MAC Vendor have a unique prefix in their MAC Address but the problem is that I don't know which one for real and which one for virtual
https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob_plain;f=manuf